# Using auto layout in UITableviewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uitextview

I am trying to use auto sizing `UITableView` cells in swift with snapKit! relevant flags set on the `UITableView` are as follows:

```
self.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.estimatedRowHeight = 70.0
```

I have a UITextField defined in my customUITableviewCell class like:

```
var uidTextField: UITextField = UITextField()
```

and the initial setup of the text field in my custom `UITableViewCell` looks like this:

```
self.contentView.addSubview(uidTextField)
uidTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Woo Hoo", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.lightGrayColor()])
uidTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
uidTextField.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(19)
uidTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
uidTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No
uidTextField.delegate = self
uidTextField.addTarget(self, action: "uidFieldChanged", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
uidTextField.snp_makeConstraints { make in 
    make.left.equalTo(self.contentView).offset(10)
    make.right.equalTo(self.contentView)
    make.top.equalTo(self.contentView).offset(10)
    make.bottom.equalTo(self.contentView).offset(10)
}
```

when I run the code it shows up cut off and gives me an error in the console that reads:

> Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously
>   suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're
>   considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height
>   instead.

Is there something wrong with my autoLayout constraints or is this an issue with UIControls and autosizing of `UITableView` cells?

Answer (score 2):

In SnapKit (and Masonry) you have to use negative values to add a padding to the right or bottom of a view. You are using `offset(10)` on your `bottom` constraint which causes the effect that the bottom 10pt of your text field will get cut off.

To fix this you have to give your bottom constraint a negative offset:

```
uidTextField.snp_makeConstraints { make in 
    make.left.equalTo(self.contentView).offset(10)
    make.right.equalTo(self.contentView)
    make.top.equalTo(self.contentView).offset(10)
    make.bottom.equalTo(self.contentView).offset(-10)
}
```

Or you could get the same constraints by doing this:

```
uidTextField.snp_makeConstraints { make in 
    make.edges.equalTo(contentView).inset(UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 0))
}
```

When you are using the `inset()` way you have to use positive values for right and bottom inset.

I don't understand why SnapKit uses negative values for bottom and right. I think that's counterintuitive and a bit confusing.

**EDIT**: This is a little example that is working fine (I hardcoded a tableView with 3 custom cells that include a `UITextField`):

**ViewController:**

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let tableView = UITableView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 70
        tableView.registerClass(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")

        tableView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.edges.equalTo(view)
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}
```

**CustomTableViewCell**:

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    let textField = UITextField()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Woo Hoo", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.lightGrayColor()])
        textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
        textField.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(19)
        textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
        textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No
        contentView.addSubview(textField)

        textField.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.edges.equalTo(contentView).inset(UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 0))
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, sorry I did not get back to you today, however the cell is still not properly sizing when using inset rather then offset like you suggested. Same error:
Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead
Although I do believe you are correct with the misuse of the offset. I am still looking into this

Comment: Does your `UITextField` have a constant height?

Comment: It does not, I was assuming that it would have an intrinsic or given height based on text height. I will try giving it a height

Comment: I get an conflict in constraints error after specifying height
 "<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x7fb9cad1de50@/Users/chris.wineland/Desktop/tableViewCellController.swift#55 UITextField:0x7fb9cad4c5f0.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fb9cad4c9a0.top + 10.0>",
    "<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x7fb9cad20370@/Users/chris.wineland/Desktop/tableViewCellController.swift#55 UITextField:0x7fb9cad4c5f0.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fb9cad4c9a0.bottom - 10.0>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb9cad52ae0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fb9cad4c9a0(44)]>"

Comment: Try overriding the system's height contraint for the contentView by giving the contentView a height constraint: `make.height.equalTo(uidTextField)`

Comment: after setting the height of the content view i am getting a very similar error around conflicting constraints.
one odd thing that i am noticing is that 

func sizeThatFits(size: CGSize) -> CGSize

is being called, I was under the impression that was not called when using autolayout, there is a similar function to that for auotlayout

Comment: I tried to reproduce the error you get, but everything is working as expected without any error. Please see my edited answer for the code I used. Maybe you are doing something differently?